# Problem with fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and for $x\in [0,1]$ we have
$$
\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt=\int_{x}^{1} f(t) \,dt.
$$
Prove that $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$.

My attempt:

Since $\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt=-\int_{1}^{x} f(t)\, dt$, then differentiating with respect to $x$, yileds $f(x)=-f(x)$, which is equivalent to $f(x)=0$.
However, I'm not sure about $\frac{d}{dx}-\int_{1}^{x} f(t) \,dt=-f(x)$ since $1\geq x$.

Thanks.

Comment: It is correct, apart from the wrong constant.

Comment: But in the proof of fundamental theorem of calculus, that is $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt=f(x)$, one assume that $a\leq x$.

Comment: Yes, but in another theorem that you proved, $\int_b^a f(t)\,dt=-\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: @tes : your attempt is 100% correct.  $\frac{d}{dt} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$ for all $a$, even $a > x$.  This can be proven from the fact/definition/convention/whatever $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt = -\int_b^a f(t)\,dt$ and a version of "$\frac{d}{dt} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$" that assumes $a \leq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct! We have $\int_x^1 f(t)\,dt=-\int_1^x f(t)\,dt$. The derivative of this, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, is $-f(x)$, and you can continue exactly like you did.

Let's do this a slightly different, but equivalent way. Let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $f(t)$. Then $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(0)$ and $\int_x^1 f(t)\,dt=F(1)-F(x)$. By what we were given, we have
$$F(x)-F(0)=F(1)-F(x)$$
for all $x$, and therefore, by differentiation, $f(x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Why "almost"?  What is the difference between what you did and what the original poster did?